# Get the result of the first condition in the query

Tags: sql

I want to make a query that searches the table for names of cities and that the result will be names of cities that start with the letter b and then names of cities that contain the letter b.

```
select *
from tb_city
where name like 'b%' or name like '%b%'
```

How can I first get the cities that start with the letter b and then the cities that contain the letter b?
The result I get is mixed

Comment: The `'%b%'` result will also include the `'b%'` result, so the latter one isn't needed.

Comment: Use a `case` expression in the ORDER BY to get the desired result.

Comment: Yes, but first I want to get the cities that start with the letter b and then the cities that contain the letter b, if I only use '%b%' then I won't be able to limit which results to get first

Comment: As said, use ORDER BY to get the `'b%'` rows first.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to order sql results starting with a certain string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22981031/how-to-order-sql-results-starting-with-a-certain-string)

Answer (score 0):

you need to use union all for this.

```
select *
from tb_city
where name like 'b%' 
union all
select *
from tb_city
where  name like '%b%' and name not like 'b%'
```

Comment: Don't expect any difference using this.

Comment: please check this link https://dbfiddle.uk/XabWnh9i

Comment: No, he does not need an UNION for that, adding a meaningful ORDER BY clause is easier and much better.

Comment: @sanjaypatel, you **always** need an explicit `ORDER BY` if you want a specific result set order. Your small example might give you that order right now, but if you add more data, constraints etc. the order will change.

Answer (score 0):

For conditional logic where you want to inspect *and* sort by the results of individual constraints you can use UNION, but you will need to add a *discriminator* or sort indicator column to identify the difference between the result sets. Note that this will however result in duplicate rows unless you deliberately exclude the `'b%'` from the `'%b%'` result sets:

```
SELECT *, SortOrder = 0
FROM tb_city
WHERE name LIKE 'b%' 
UNION ALL
SELECT *, SortOrder = 1
FROM tb_city
WHERE name like '%b%' and name NOT LIKE 'b%'
ORDER BY SortOrder
```

> **NOTE:** only the *last* SELECT in the set can have the `ORDER BY` clause, the order is evaluated *after* the result sets are combined

An alternate solution that works well form multiple criteria, is to use a case statement to determine the sort. Using `CASE` will make it easier to ensure that you only get 1 of each record, without having to write the criteria as a mutually exclusive set:

```
SELECT *
FROM tb_city
WHERE name LIKE 'b%' or name LIKE '%b%'
ORDER BY CASE 
             WHEN name LIKE 'b%' THEN 0 
             WHEN name LIKE '%b%' THEN 1
             ELSE 2
         END
```

> **NOTE:** It is good practise to specify a *default* constraint in your case statements, especially when using this conditional expression for sorting. If your `WHERE` criteria becomes out of sync with the `CASE` it might result in additional rows in the results, if no `ELSE` is specified then the extra rows will have a value of `NULL`, in SQL Server that will mean they will be sorted *before* the 0s. (In other RDBMS this behaviour is configurable and the defaults may not be what you expect...)
>
> - Remove any ambiguity be being explicit with your sorting and make sure you cover all bases.

The problem with a resultset like this that uses `CASE` directly in the `ORDER BY`  though can be that it is hard to visualise why the results are rendered in that order, it can be hard to confirm the sequence logic.

If you want to debug the sorting criteria or just need to *know* why the data is sorted in a specific way, you can moe the `CASE` out to an expression based column in the set, like the `UNION` solution, we add in the discriminator column:

```
SELECT *
     , CASE 
           WHEN name LIKE 'b%' THEN 0 
           WHEN name LIKE '%b%' THEN 1
           ELSE 2
       END as SortOrder
FROM tb_city
WHERE name LIKE 'b%' or name LIKE '%b%'
ORDER BY SortOrder
```

There is no significant performance difference between this and the previous query other than the additional bytes over the wire, by referencing the alias of the `SortOrder` expression the expression will not be re-evaluated.